# get-content : Cannot find path 'PATH_TO_FILE_' because it does not exsist

Tags: powershell

I am writing a PS Script to try and locate a folder on a remote server. Here is the code:

```
# Set file to be tested for, put everything after c:\
# “c:\Users\Default” is the example path
$filetofind = "EventLogs"
# Hostnames TXT Location
$hostnamestxt = "C:\Scripts\Powershell_Remote_File_Query\hosts.txt"
# Destination file for Online Machines
$onlinetxt = "C:\Scripts\Powershell_Remote_File_Query\Machines_with_file.txt"
# Destination file for Offline Machines
$offlinetxt = "C:\Scripts\Powershell_Remote_File_Query\Offline_Machines.txt"

##########################################################
# Begin Executing Script – Do Not Edit Below This Line
##########################################################
$computers = get-content “$hostnamestxt”

write-host “———————————————-”
write-host “Scanning hostnames from $hostnamestxt…”
write-host “———————————————-”

foreach($computer in $computers)
{
ping -n 1 $computer >$null
if($lastexitcode -eq 0)
{
if(test-path “\\$computer\c$\$filetofind”)
{
echo “$computer” | Out-File -Append “$onlinetxt”
write-host “File FOUND on $computer”
}
else
{write-host “File NOT found on $computer”}
}
else
{
echo “$computer” | Out-File -Append “$offlinetxt”
write-host “$computer is OFFLINE/DID NOT RESPOND TO PING”
}
}
write-host “———————————————-”
write-host “Script has completed please check output.”
write-host “Hosts with file output location – $onlinetxt”
write-host “Hosts that were unpingable output location – $offlinetxt”
write-host “———————————————-“
```

I get this error when running the script:

```
get-content : Cannot find path 'C:\Scripts\Powershell_Remote_File_Query\â€œ€' because it does not exist.
At C:\Scripts\Powershell_Remote_File_Query\Powershell_Remote_File_Query_Script.ps1:24 char:18
+     $computers = get-content â€œ$hostnamestxtâ€
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Scripts\Powe...ile_Query\â€œ€:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundEx
   ception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

Both the script itself and the txt file are in the same directory. Please forgive me I'm new to Powershell and not a programmer by any means.

Comment: `$computers = get-content â€œ$hostnamestxtâ€` So, just so you know, encoding matters.  Your `.ps1` files should be `utf8` encoded, otherwise you'll run into interpreter issues.  Get a reasonable editor (`vscode`), save it with proper encoding and fix glyph issues.

Comment: It was encoded in Notepadd++ using UTF-8. I thought it was some encoding issues but its UTF-8.

Comment: It **is** encoding.  Your error message makes that abundantly clear.

Comment: I threw the code into VSCode and then saved it with UTF-8 encoding and ran it again, still got the same error. How do I know its encoding right?

Comment: Did you look at the code again to make sure the glyphs didn't get copied into the code?

Comment: Yes, I double checked to make sure the code same. To be safe, I re-downloaded the script, opened it in VSCode and then changed the parameters and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this...

```
$hostnamestxt = "C:\Scripts\Powershell_Remote_File_Query\hosts.txt"
$computers = get-content “$hostnamestxt”
```

Try just doing this...

```
$computers = get-content "C:\Scripts\Powershell_Remote_File_Query\hosts.txt"
```

I understand what you are trying to do should result to the same thing, yet, let's just try to eliminate that extra thing, and give it a shot to see if you get a different result.

Also, if that file you are reading is on a remote host, then you should be using the UNC file share path, not your local C: drive. Just assuming a bit here.